# Gluon Mobile Navigation-Drawer icons do not appear

Tags: javafx, mobile, gluon, graalvm

We are evaluating Gluon Mobile for our project. We are using IntelliJ Idea as our IDE, we download the Gluon plugin and create the project. On PC it runs perfect, the icons appear, but when running on the android device, the Navigation-Drawer icons disappear

Operating System: Fedora 34 64 Bits
Java: OpenJdk 17
JavaFX: 17.0.2
Gluon Plugin: 1.0.12
GraalVM: 22.0.0.3

Comment: Can you try GraalVM 22.0.0.3 for JDK *11*? It seems there is some issue while trying to load the fonts on JDK 17.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1114 to track this issue

Comment: Thanks Jose, I changed my environment to jdk11 and everything worked fine.