# Gluon - MaterialDesignIcon not showing in Android

Tags: android, gluon, gluon-mobile

My enviroment is java-17-openjdk-amd64, graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.0.0.3-Final, javafx-sdk-17.0.2 and apache-maven-3.8.4

When I run the app on my desktop Ubuntu Linux it's ok, the icons are showing, but when I nativerun on my smartphone Android they are not showing.

As in the printscreen bellow.

What can I do?

[on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDgUP.png)

[on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHXyY.png)

Comment: @JoséPereda has any idea?

Comment: Yes, same as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026569/gluon-mobile-navigation-drawer-icons-do-not-appear, see comment

Comment: Right, with graalvm with jdk11 works perfectely. Muchas gracias @JoséPereda.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1114 to track this issue